# Dataweave: Merge 2 arrays based upon condition

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have 2 arrays stored in a variable as

vars.array1

```
[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Sam",
        "class": "first"
    },
    {
        "id": 124,
        "name": "John",
        "class": "first"
    },
    {
        "id": 125,
        "name": "Max",
        "class": "second"
    }
]
```

vars.array2

```
[
    {
        "studentId": 123,
        "course": "science",
        "otherActivities": "sports"
    },
    {
        "studentId": 125,
        "course": "arts",
        "otherActivities": "studentCouncil"
    },
    {
        "studentId": 126,
        "course": "literature",
        "otherActivities": "drama"
    }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Sam",
        "class": "first",
        "course": "science",
        "otherActivities": "sports"
    },
    {
        "id": 125,
        "name": "Max",
        "class": "second",
        "course": "arts",
        "otherActivities": "studentCouncil"
    }
]
```

The original arrays contains around 5000.

Right now, i am using this as solution,

```
//this code is inside 'for each' with collection as vars.array1
//vars.array3 is inilialised as [] before 'for each'
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
if(sizeOf(vars.array2 filter $["studentId"] == payload.id) > 0)
(vars.array3 << (payload ++ (vars.array2 filter $["studentId"] == payload.id)[0]))
else vars.array3
```

This works fine with around 500 records but takes time 5k records. Wondering if there is any other way to reduce the complexity which would give faster response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using [join](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-arrays-functions-join) ?

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var array1=[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Sam",
        "class": "first"
    },
    {
        "id": 124,
        "name": "John",
        "class": "first"
    },
    {
        "id": 125,
        "name": "Max",
        "class": "second"
    }
]
var array2=[
    {
        "studentId": 123,
        "course": "science",
        "otherActivities": "sports"
    },
    {
        "studentId": 125,
        "course": "arts",
        "otherActivities": "studentCouncil"
    },
    {
        "studentId": 126,
        "course": "literature",
        "otherActivities": "drama"
    }
]
---
join(array1, array2, (a1) -> a1.id, (a2) -> a2.studentId) map {
     ($.l ++ $.r - "studentId" )
}
```

Comment: This works as expected and faster. Thanks @SalimKhan

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays are sorted using id then you can use binary search to chop off your complexity of search.

Comment: can you give an example? that might help more

Comment: how is a binary search related to the question? And how would it be implemented in DataWeave?